# Show Multiple occurrences of items in a list, sml

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I'm trying to show the indices of all multiple occurrences for an element in a list.

in standard ml.

but my code show the empty list :(

this is my code:

```
    fun index(item, xs,ys) =
let
fun index'(m, nil , ys) = (
  SOME (ys) )
| index'(m, x::xr , ys) = if x = item then(
  (ys @ [m]);
  index'(m + 1, xr , ys)
  )
  else index'(m + 1, xr,ys)
in
index'(0, xs , ys)
end;


index(1,[1,2,1,4,5,1],[]);
```

can you help me?

Comment: Please indent and format your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first:

1. `index` should take two arguments; the element to look for and the list to look for it in.
   The accumulation parameter belongs to the helper function.
2. It is meaningless to always produce `SOME` of something and never `NONE`.

Let's fix these first.

```
fun index (item, xs) =
    let
        fun index'(m, nil , ys) = ys
          | index'(m, x::xr, ys) = if x = item then(
                                       (ys @ [m]);
                                       index'(m + 1, xr , ys)
                                   )
                                   else index'(m + 1, xr,ys)
    in
        index'(0, xs, [])
end;
```

Now you don't need to pass the extra accumulator parameter when you use `index`.
It's also impossible to start with something other than `[]`.

Your next, and main, problem is

```
(ys @ [m]);
index'(m + 1, xr , ys)
```

which first creates the list `ys @ [m]`, immediately throws it away, and then produces as its result `index'(m + 1, xr , ys)`, which is exactly what the `else` branch does.

That is, the conditional is equivalent to

```
if x = item
then index'(m + 1, xr, ys)
else index'(m + 1, xr, ys)
```

and thus, `index'` is equivalent to

```
fun index'(m, nil, ys) = ys
  | index'(m, x::xr, ys) = index'(m + 1, xr, ys)
```

Since you always pass the original `ys` along, and it is `[]` to start with, the result is always `[]`.

What you need to do is to pass the extended list to the recursion, so it can become the result when the recursion terminates.
Renaming the accumulator `ys` to make its purpose clearer:

```
fun index (item, xs) =
    let
        fun index'(i, nil, accumulator) = accumulator
          | index'(i, x::xr, accumulator) = if x = item
                                            then index' (i + 1, xr, accumulator @ [i])
                                            else index' (i + 1, xr, accumulator)
    in
        index'(0, xs, [])
end;
```

This is inefficient, due to the repeated appending of an element to the back of a list.
It is very common to accumulate in reverse, and correct it when you're done.
(This "feels" inefficient, but it isn't.)

```
fun index (item, xs) =
    let
        fun index'(i, nil, accumulator) = List.reverse accumulator
          | index'(i, x::xr, accumulator) = if x = item
                                            then index' (i + 1, xr, i::accumulator)
                                            else index' (i + 1, xr, accumulator)
    in
        index'(0, xs, [])
end;
```